# How to write a program that wraps both STDOUT and STDIN of another program?

Tags: ruby, unix, stdout, stdin, pipeline

I want to write a simple automation tool in Ruby that is supposed to wrap a command-line program.

The command-line program works somewhat like a REPL: Commands can be entered through STDIN, and output is returned to STDOUT. The Ruby tool therefore needs to be able to read input from the program's STDOUT, as well as return new commands to the programs STDIN.

How can such a cyclic input/output be set up?
I am not entirely sure if this question relates to Ruby, or if it relates more to how streams can be connected in Unix-systems in general.

Comment: Please read "[ask]". You're asking us to explain how to do something that you should have researched, then tried writing code, then asked a specific question about. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)" Instead you're asking us for a tutorial. Ruby has multiple ways to do what you want. The documentation for the [Open3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) class will help explain, as will various pages on the internet.

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you very much for your comment. I have had no luck so far with finding anything about how to connect a program two-way to another program. I also had no idea what **jargon** could be used to properly describe such a situation. This is why I asked the question. Of course, the 'how much research is required' is something very subjective, so I totally understand your reason for downvoting. In any case, your link to the Open3 module already greatly helps. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicate with subprocess in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590702/communicate-with-subprocess-in-ruby)

Comment: Don't take it the wrong way, but this question is too vague. For a REPL tool you might want to look at [the readline module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html) as well as Open3 which is great for wrapping sub-processes. To have avoided the friction here remember the Stack Overflow principle: Show what you've tried, *especially* if it's code.

Answer (score 2):

That's quite simple to achieve with [IO.popen](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-popen)

```
handler = IO.popen("bash","w+")

handler.puts("whoami")
puts handler.gets

handler.puts("date")
puts handler.gets

handler.close
```

Output:

```
wrodevlopot:tmp lopot$ ruby test.rb 
lopot
Sat Oct  1 21:57:42 CEST 2016
```

IO.popen returns an IO handler, mind you that we are opening the subprocess with `w+` which means read and write. In the example above we are opening a bash process sending the command `whoami`, then we read from it and print, same for command `date`, Once we're done with the subprocess we call close.